# Placing text in a cases environment

Tags: align

How can I place the text `(a case)` at the end of the last bracket?

```
\begin{align}
    P_{12}=
    \begin{cases} 
    \begin{split}
   -\biggl(\left [ \text{Some expression here} \right ]\\-\left [ \text{Some expression here}\right ]\biggr)
    \end{split} 
    \text{a case}
    \end{cases}   
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the following cases [pun intended]? It wasn't clear to me if you want to place "a case" and "another case" vertically centered or at the bottom of the expression to the immdiate left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'dcases' env.

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P_{12}= 
\begin{dcases}
\begin{aligned}
-\Bigl( [ \text{Some expression here}]& \\
-       [ \text{Some expression here}]& \Bigr)
\end{aligned} 
& \text{a case}  \\[3ex]
\begin{aligned}[b]
-\Bigl( [ \text{Some expression here}]& \\
-       [ \text{Some expression here}]& \Bigr)
\end{aligned} 
& \text{another case} 
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The way you've placed "another case" is exactly what I was trying. Thank you so much!